# If $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra, then $H^1 (A, D(A)) = \{ 0 \}$ (first cohomology group )?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

If $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra, then $H^1 (A, D(A)) = \{ 0 \}$ (first cohomology group )?
We don't know that is an open problem or it has counterexample...

Comment: And what is $D(A)$? And which cohomology are you referring to?

Comment: $D(A)$  : its double centralizer $A$,

Comment: The set of all derivations from $A$ into $X$ is denoted by $Z^1(A, X)$, and the set of all inner derivations from $A$ into $X$ is denoted by $B^1(A, X)$. Then $H^1(A, X) =  Z^1(A,X) / B^1( A,X) $ is
the first Hochschild cohomology group of $A$ with coefficients in $X$.

Comment: Dear anonymous user: presumably you are only interested in _continuous_ derivations?

Comment: Also: is this also your user account? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256095/is-any-derivation-from-a-c-algebra-a-into-its-double-centralizer-inner or  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038734/is-any-derivation-from-a-c-algebra-a-into-its-double-centralizer-inner

Comment: I would appreciate it even more if you clarified the issue concerning multiple accounts

Answer (score 2):

No. See Elliott's paper [Some C$^*$ algebras with outer derivations](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1250131229), which classifies all separable C$^*$-algebras for which this is true.